# Don't apply CGAffineTransform to subviews during scaling

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiscrollview

I am trying to zoom a `UIImageView` which is subview of a `UIScrollView`. So, I have added a UIView as a container to a UIScrollView. I am applying scale to containerView, so that UIImageView also scales. I have 2 more UIView as subviews in ScrollContainer view. When I am applying transform to scrollContainer I don't want to apply transform to 2 subviews.

so i tried to do in this way:

```
self.cropPointViewBottomLeft.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1 / self.scrollView.zoomScale, 1 / self.scrollView.zoomScale);
self.cropPointViewBottomRight.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1 /self.scrollView.zoomScale, 1 / self.scrollView.zoomScale);
```

`cropPointViewBottomLeft` & `cropPointViewBottomRight` are not scaling but these two are shrinking. so during crop, getting problem.

I need to know exactly how MKMap zoom works with annotations.

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to do this?  I need to do the same and was wondering how you solved it

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this and see

```
self.cropPointViewBottomLeft.transform=CGAffineTransformTranslate(self.cropPointViewBottomLeft.transform,
      1 / self.scrollView.zoomScale, 1 / self.scrollView.zoomScale)
```

Comment: No that won't help. In my sample user will be placing those UIViews on the right & left of UIImageView for cropping. So when we will be scaling those 2 UIViews shouldn't change its position.